# Linux pci_map_single working

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, dma, pci

My question is regarding the use of the pci_map_single function. I know that a DMA address is generated which the device can use for data transfer but does any change happen to the memory(virtual address pointer) that is passed as an argument to this function?

Comment: It's marked uncached on some systems. When system is cache coherent (e.g. x86), the function is actually no-op. Oh, wait, it does address translation to the bus addr, which in case of IOMMU would be different story. So, everything depends on architecture in use.

Comment: @andy For generic applications what function can be used to mark the memory as uncached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, virtual address is not going to change. Virtual address is passed by value not passed be reference.

On successful completion, DMA address is retured.